# thmtools - Align theorem header

Tags: spacing, amsthm, thmtools

How to prevent LaTeX from creating stretching space inside theorem headers, using a thmtools theorem?

In this example, I want **"Theorem 1. "** to be aligned with **"Theorem 2. "**.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
            headfont=\bfseries,
            notefont=\bfseries,
            notebraces={(}{)},
            bodyfont=\itshape,
            qed=,
            headpunct = .
            ]{custom}

\declaretheorem[style = custom, name = Theorem]{thm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{thm}
        This is a small theorem.
    \end{thm}
    \begin{thm}
        This is a theorem which is a little bit larger and that ends withareallybigword.
    \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the stretching, you can place the head in an `\mbox`, for instance. The formatting of the theorem's head can be changed using the `headformat` key in `\declaretheoremstyle`.

Here's a complete example built on yours.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
            headfont=\bfseries,
            notefont=\bfseries,
            notebraces={(}{)},
            bodyfont=\itshape,
            qed=,
            headpunct=.,
            headformat={\mbox{\NAME{} \NUMBER\NOTE}}
            ]{custom}

\declaretheorem[style=custom, name=Theorem]{thm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{thm}
        This is a small theorem.
    \end{thm}
    \begin{thm}
        This is a theorem which is a little bit larger and that ends withareallybigword.
    \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]